# Get-ADUser -properties: only want to show one attribute

Tags: powershell, properties, attributes

I'm trying to pull one attribute from a user. However, the `-properties` parameter pulls in the default parameters plus the one I'm looking for. Is there a way to prevent the default values from showing up?

Line looks like this:

```
Get-ADUser -identity "name" -properties "attributename"
```

Comment: no, you cannot do that with the AD cmdlets. i _think_ you can do it with the direct adsi search, but i am unsure of that.

Comment: What's provoking the question? There's no advantage to outputting only a single attribute, unless you think you _must_ do so for some reason (hence my question).

Comment: Are you trying to not pull the other properties, or only keep the one you are interested in? If for some reason you want to not get the default properties at all you'll want to use the `[adsisearcher]` accelerator, which only has 1 property that must be kept, which is ADsPath (such as `LDAP://CN=Bob,OU=Users,DC=TacoTruck,DC=ORG`), but that makes things much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$myAttr = (Get-ADUser -identity "name" -properties attributename).attributename
```

Select-Object cmdlet  creates new custom objects that contain properties selected from the object. As such, their type Is NoteProperty.

References here:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vishinde/2012/08/27/expandproperty-in-select-object/

Comment: You can use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` to get only the value(s) of the property (instead of custom objects).

Comment: Exactly. Moreover, if the value is a collection, expandproperty will expand it. I find the notation I proposed more concise, though.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what, you will always get the default properties if you keep it as an `ADUser` object. If you want to only show one property, then the easiest is to pipe it through a `Select` statement which will filter out every thing else and only return the property you want:

```
Get-ADUser -identity "name" -properties "attributename" | Select "attributename"
```